# How to override >2499 character error in Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sqlplus

I have a Oracle query which I'm executing through shell script and in that my query is getting exceeded the maximum length of 2499.

I'm getting error

> SP2-0027: INPUT IS TOO LONG(> 2499 CHARACTERS) - LINE IGNORED

Comment: What is the error message and how does your script look like? I am not aware of such limit.

Comment: `exceeded the maximum length of 2499` of what ?

Comment: I'm getting error SP2-0027: INPUT IS TOO LONG(> 2499 CHARACTERS) - LINE IGNORED

Comment: Why do you have a 2500+ character long SQL query anyways?

Comment: SQLPlus has command line size limit
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/225352/sqlplus-sp2-0341-line-overflow-during-variable-substitution
use dump file or sqlLoader

Answer (score 12):

Here are some options for working around SQL*Plus line length limitations:

1. **Upgrade to 12.2(?) client.**  On 12.2 the client allows up to 4999 characters.  Which is infuriating in a way - if Oracle finally admits that 2499 is not enough, why did they only increase the limit to 4999?
2. **Add line breaks.**  Split the results into multiple lines.  If using Windows make sure to use both carriage return and newline - `chr(13)||chr(10)`.
3. **Use another program.**  Many programs have a SQL*Plus-like option.  In general I recommend *not* using a SQL*Plus clone.  The main advantage of SQL*Plus is that it's a simple tool and works just about the same everywhere.  None of the SQL*Plus clones are fully compatible and many programs will break if you run SQL*Plus scripts on a clone.

Comment: 4999 is useless, we have more than 20000 strings  in single line.... poor Oracle client, when you open some tool UI tool it will hang.

Comment: Critical note - even in the latest version of Oracle (21c), there is a limit called "SQL or PL/SQL command- line size after variable substitution" which is 3000. If your commands are constructed with variable substitution, 3000 is the limit, period.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a line break somewhere in that *long line*; that's a limitation of SQL*Plus and, as far as I can tell, you can't avoid it by some setting (like SET LINESIZE 100 and similar).